# When defining Vector<?> is useful?

Tags: java, raw-types, generic-type-argument

When following container will be useful

```
        Vector<?> wilcardVector;
```

if only I can do with this is to create new  container

```
    wilcardVector = new Vector<String>();
```

or to add `null` value

```
    wilcardVector.add(null);
```

Trying to add some other types or pass with different generic method fails when compiling. So what is it for?

Comment: can you provide some more details on what you are asking?

Comment: Unless you really have to, I would use a List like ArrayList.  Vector is a legacy class IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One valid use case for unbounded wildcard is to use it as a method parameter, when you only use those Vector's methods independent of type parameter, such as `size()`, `isEmpty()`, etc. :

something like :

```
void sampleMethod(Vector<?> vector) {

    if (vector.isEmpty()) {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

and compiler will allow to pass any `Vector` to `sampleMethod` above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector<?> wilcardVector;
```

means

```
Vector<?> wilcardVector=null;
```

and calling `wilcardVector.add(null);` will lead to exception as wilcardVector=null

So, you ahve to use

```
wilcardVector = new Vector<String>();
```

`wilcardVector = new Vector<String>();` should be sued when you are adding "only" Strings and nothing else.